# Increment a character value to display all pictures in a directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, kivy, kivy-language

I have a directory filled with 12 drawings of animals. I want to display them on a 4x3 grid without having any duplicates. I am using kivy. I have the code to get the filenames from the directory, randomize the names, and link the name to the image for to display. In my .kv file I have 12 Images declared with id: a-l and source: '<'random_name'>.jpg'. I am trying to use a while loop to increment the initial char value from "`" to "l" so that every time the random loop repeats char is incremented in the line

```
self.ids.char.source = rand_img
```

UPDATE** 
I have added the super() function and I no longer get an error but none of my images are populated to my grid

main.py

```
class AnimalsTest1(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AnimalsTest1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        def on_pre_enter(self):
            path = "img_directory"
            files = []
            for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
                for file in f:
                    if '.jpg' in file:
                        files.append(os.path.join(r, file))

            for f in files:
                f = random.choice([
                    x for x in os.listdir(path)
                    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, x))
                    ])
                char = "`"
                while char != "l":
                    char = chr(ord(char)+1)
                    print(char)
                    rand_img = ("img_directory" + str(f))
                    self.ids.char.source = rand_img
                    print(f)
```

animalstest1.kv

```
#:import utils kivy.utils

<AnimalsTest1>:
    GridLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#000000")
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        cols: 4
        rows: 5
        Image:
            id: a
            source: '<random_name>.jpg'
        .
        .
        .
        Image:
            id: l
            source: '<random_name>.jpg'
    Button:
        pos_hint: {"top": .1, "right": 1}
        size_hint: .1, .1
        text:
            "begin dot game"
        on_release:
            app.change_screen("game1")
```

Comment: I don't see a `char` `id` in your `kv`, but you are trying to reference one in `self.ids.char.source = rand_img`.

Comment: My char is defined in my main.py it is `char = "``"`. My id in my .kv are `a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l`. I am trying to increment char to the characters in my .kv so that when the line of `self.ids.char.source = rand_img` is reached char will be replaced with the corresponding character.

Comment: Then try `self.ids[char].source = rand_img`.

Comment: Placing the brackets around char didn't work.